# comparison between spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

There a lot of function spaces and would be nice if somebody can correct me if I am wrong in comparing a few. I want to compare $C^2,L^2,W^{2,2}$ (continuous up to third derivative, Hilbert space of square integrable functions and Sobolev with second weak derivative in $L^2$) of functions defined on a compact set.
I think $C^2\subset W^{2,2}\subset L^2$. Is that the right inclusion? thanks!

Comment: In the case of open bounded sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, yes, this is true.

Comment: I guess you cold take a look at the Evans's "Partial Differential Equations", chapter 5. There you will find lots of inclusions of space of functions as linear bounded (and sometimes compact) operators between these spaces.

Comment: @matgaio Is it true for open bounded $\Omega$ (not closed bounded)? $C^2\subset W^{2,2}$ without assuming any integrability for the functions in $C^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. Note that a continuous function on a compact set is square integrable (because it is bounded and a compact set has finite measure), and if the classical derivative exists then the weak derivative exists and they are equal. Thus $C^2$-functions are twice weakly differentiable and the derivatives are again square integrable because they are continuous. In other words, $C^2 \subset W^{2,2}$. Functions in $W^{2,2}$ are square integrable by definition, so we have $W^{2,2} \subset L^2$.

An interesting question for you to ponder is: are the inclusion maps continuous? That is: is the map $f \mapsto f$ bounded from $C^2$ to $W^{2,2}$ and from $W^{2,2}$ to $L^2$?